# How to call server side method using router functionality in node.js?

Tags: node.js

I want to use router functionality of node to call server side methods. I am not using express generator to generate project structure.

Comment: is this helping ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18401407/how-to-invoke-server-side-function-from-client-side-using-socket-io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some changes to the code in the answer by Mukesh Sharma and made it work:

Server.js (Server code)

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();


var routes = require('./FirstAppServer/route');
app.use('/', routes);

// //set static folder
app.use(express.static('FirstApp/public'));
app.use('/module', express.static('node_modules'));

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Port 3000');
});
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('login.html');
});

module.exports = app;
```

route.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/endpoint', function (req, res, next) {        
    console.log('Server side call');
    next();
});

module.exports = router;
```

test.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Login</title>
  <script src="js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        testServerCall();
    });
    function testServerCall(){
      debugger;
      $.ajax({
          type:"post",
          url:"/endpoint",
          data:{
            "a":"a" 
          },
          success:function(){
            console.log('success');
          },
          error:function(){
            console.log('error');
          }
        });
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="divLogin">
    <input type="text" id="txtUsername" />
  </div>
  <h2>Login</h2>
  <a href="createUser.html">Create User</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define routes in different file and can import in the `server.js` .

**server.js** - Server code

```
var express =require('express');
var apis = require('./api.js');
var app = express();

app.use('/api', apis);

app.listen(3000);
```

**api.js** - Api router

```
var express =require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/users', function (req, res) {
  return res.json([{
     name: 'John Doe',
     email: 'john@doe.com'
  }]);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Hope it helps you.